# Can I use an aversive to keep my cat from licking my plate?

Tags: cats, training

My normal morning routine is to make some eggs and coffee, and browse the internet while eating my eggs and drinking my coffee. After finishing my eggs but before finishing my coffee, I'll put my plate to the side on my desk.

Romeo has developed a habit of jumping up on the desk immediately to lick my plate for any egg remnants. He loves eggs I guess. I put him back on the floor, but he just jumps back up.

The obvious solution is to take my plate downstairs but I haven't finished my coffee yet! Is there an aversive (I was thinking hot sauce) that I could put on my plate to get him to stop this behavior? Obviously I don't want it to be HARMFUL but I do want it to be unpleasant. Also it should wash off in the dishwasher for the next time I use the plate.

Comment: I used to have a cat that would eat bits of chicken from hot wings with sauce on them.  Cats may not be as troubled by pepper as you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have permission to relay this exchange, and will definitely be trying this.

[image]

Comment: An opaque plate cover like a pot lid or fry pan lid that fits over the plate would also work and not get a napkin messy. A glass one would work with a napkin over it.